# Evaluate dynamic condition in PL/pgSQL using EXECUTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function that needs to dynamically validate the input based on the value type. It does this by finding the constraint in another table, but for simplicity I provide the constraint as well in the function below.

This other table contains (value_type, value_constraint), where value_constraint is a text field that contains e.g. `value::int > 0`. I need to dynamically check this constraint within my insert function. I was trying to do that using `EXECUTE` as seen below, but it's not working.

How do I dynamically execute a condition statement and get the value as a boolean into `v_successful_insert`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_value(p_value_type text, p_value_constraint text, p_value text) RETURNS boolean
    AS $$
    DECLARE
        v_successful_insert bool;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE p_value_constraint INTO v_successful_insert;

        IF v_successful_insert THEN
            INSERT INTO my_table (value_type, value)
            VALUES (p_value_type, p_value);
        END IF;
        RETURN v_successful_insert;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile;
```

The code is run on Postgresql 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `SELECT` in the execute. For example:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    p_value TEXT := 'x';
    p_value_constraint TEXT := '::int > 0';
    result BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT $1' || p_value_constraint
        INTO result
        USING p_value;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION THEN
            result := FALSE;
    END;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', result;
END $$
```

Prints FALSE

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Is it possible to make an error in the EXECUTE step not cause issues, but just make `v_successful_insert` become false? E.g. a try/except of sorts.